# OrientDB: Select unique vertices but retain the edges

Tags: orientdb

I am trying to do the following weird thing. I have a group of edges that point towards a group of vertices, but there is some repetition - multiple edges point to the same vertices.

Given a SELECT command that gives me the list of edges, I want to:

- SELECT the unique vertices from all of the 'out' vertices
- Return, along with the @rid of the unique vertices, a list of all the edges that pointed towards them.

E.g. the result should be a list of vertices with (vertex rid, [edge 1, edge 2, edge 3]).

Another way to think about this is I want to GROUP BY outgoing vertex but somehow retain in a field the @rid's of all the edges I grouped.

Thanks!

Comment: What properties do you have on vertices? You can compare the vertices using a particular property... and than get all the out edges... What's the problem with that, can you post your schema and the queries that you are trying? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

in this you get for every vertex the outgoing edges

```
select $a.@rid, $a.outE() from 'your class'
let $a = (select from 'your class' where $parent.current.@rid = @rid)
```

if you want the ingoing vertices you have to change $a.outE() with inE(), like below:

```
select $a.@rid, $a.inE() from 'your class'
let $a = (select from 'your class' where $parent.current.@rid = @rid)
```

Hope it helps.

Regards.